# base64encoded string returned from API call is showing nil after Data(base64encoded: data) is ran

Tags: ios, swift, base64, jsondecoder

I am very confused on this one. I had been thinking it was something wrong with my server, but after testing it seems as though using Data(base64encoded: data) is producing nil even though the data is there and is in fact base64encoded.
I have tried everything I can think of and nothing is working. Here is the code I am using and the output...

```
do {
  print("DATA as a string: ", String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) ?? "NONE AVAILABLE")
  let decodedData = Data(base64encoded: data!, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
  print("DECODED DATA: ")
  print(decodedData as Any)
  let apiResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(ApiConnectionResponse.self, from: decodedData!)
  completion(.success(apiResponse))
} catch {
  completion(.failure(error))
}
```

The output from that is...

> Data as string: 
>   eyJzdWNjZXNzIjoiZmFsc2UiLCJlcnJvciI6Im1vYmlsZV9waW5fY29ubmVjdDogaW52YWxpZCBvciBleHBpcmVkIn0.
>
> DECODED DATA:  nil

So the String is a legit base64encoded string, it decodes to

> {"success":"false","error":"mobile_pin_connect: invalid or expired"}

However the decoded data is nil. I don't understand, how can it be nil when the string is a base64encoded string and is not nil.
I have even tried forcing the string in there like so...

```
let decodedData = Data(base64encoded: String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8))
```

Still no luck. It is throwing a fatal error, and I can see in the section at the bottom of Xcode that the data is in fact "(Data?) 92 bytes" What I can't figure out is why it is nil after running through Data()...

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am really lost and can't figure out why I can make the string, but not the data.

The end result of this is, I need to get JSONDecoder().decode to work with the reply from the server, I think I can get that part done, if I can figure out why it is nil after the data call. Thank you.

Comment: Can you try without `.ignoreUnknownCharacters` option?

Comment: That's how I had it at first and it was nil. After searching I found some people saying that the .ignoreUnknownCharacters option was solving it, so I tried it, no luck.

Comment: Can you encode the original data and check the string identical?

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: you need to pad the string length using `=`

Comment: I tried adding the "=" to the end of the string and still getting nil on the decodedData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check your data length, divide by 3 and in case the result is not zero add one or two bytes (65) `=` equal sign for padding your data. Try like this:

```
let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: data + .init(repeating: 65, count: data.count % 3))
```

---

```
extension Data {
    var base64encodedDataPadded: Data {
        let data = last == 46 ? dropLast() : self
        return data + .init(repeating: 65, count: data.count % 3)
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let data = Data("eyJzdWNjZXNzIjoiZmFsc2UiLCJlcnJvciI6Im1vYmlsZV9waW5fY29ubmVjdDogaW52YWxpZCBvciBleHBpcmVkIn0.".utf8)
let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: data.base64encodedDataPadded)!
print(String(data: decodedData, encoding: .utf8)!) // "{"success":"false","error":"mobile_pin_connect: invalid or expired"}"
```

Comment: I still get nil when trying to print decodedData with that. The string is coming though fine and doing a print(data) is showing (optional(92bytes)) but the actual output of decodedData is nil.

Comment: I have tested it in playground without an issue. Make sure your string doesn't finish with a period as you are showing in your post

Comment: What is the best way to remove that period if it is there?

Comment: Yay, now my data is no longer nil, it's showing as optional (69 bytes). Thank you. Now I just have to figure out what the error "Garbage at end." means when trying to use the JSONDecoder().decode

Comment: @NeglectedSanity looks like you have a null-terminated string. You can also use dropLast if the data ends with a byte == 0

Comment: I finally got it working. I had to use the dropLast(), then append a "=" for the JSONDecoder().decode to properly parse it. Thank you so much for all your help

Comment: you are welcome. you can also remove it from the decodedData `let apiResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(ApiConnectionResponse.self, from: decodedData.last == 0 ? decodedData.dropLast() : decodedData)`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the encoded data is wrong.

```
let originalString = """
{"success":"false","error":"mobile_pin_connect: invalid or expired"}
"""

let base64string = originalString.data(using: .utf8)?.base64EncodedString()
print(base64string)

let base64EncodedData = originalString.data(using: .utf8)?.base64EncodedData()
let base64EncodedString = String(data: base64EncodedData!, encoding: .utf8)
print(base64EncodedString)

let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: base64EncodedData!)
let decodedString = String(data: decodedData!, encoding: .utf8)
print(decodedString)
```

The log is as below:

```
Optional("eyJzdWNjZXNzIjoiZmFsc2UiLCJlcnJvciI6Im1vYmlsZV9waW5fY29ubmVjdDogaW52YWxpZCBvciBleHBpcmVkIn0=")
Optional("eyJzdWNjZXNzIjoiZmFsc2UiLCJlcnJvciI6Im1vYmlsZV9waW5fY29ubmVjdDogaW52YWxpZCBvciBleHBpcmVkIn0=")
Optional("{\"success\":\"false\",\"error\":\"mobile_pin_connect: invalid or expired\"}")
```

According to the base64 specification, `.` is not a valid character. `=` is the appropriate character for padding.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Answer (score 0):

You show your base64 string as having a period and a newline at the end. That doesn't look correct. An online base64 decoder decodes it with or without that final period and newline, but Swift probably chokes with it in place.